# getComponent method getting confuse with tabs on Xpages

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes

I have a Xpage where I have these Rich Text fields to be filled.

If the user open two different documents (document A and then document B) in two tabs in the navigator, and save A, the `getComponent` method gets confused and save in A the data of B document replacing the fields.
but this only happens if the user doesn't change anything, if he change the data is not replaced.

I tried to do a `XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:divWithTheData}")` in the onStart of the enventHandler of the button, to get the data refreshed and then the `getComponent` know right where it should look for, but it, obviously, didn't work.

---

Edit:
The Rich Text fields are not binded to the Data source, actually the fields that are bindeded (?) in the data source are saved correctly, they (Rich text fields) are binded to a session scoped variable named `camposRT.name`, this is why the `getComponent` method gets confused.
I have to do this, put in session scoped variable, because they are not meant to be saved in the same document of data source, they are meant to be saved in documents separated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `ignoreRequestParams="true"` set on the second datasource, or are picking up a different UNID from the query string via `requestParamPrefix`?

If not, it's not a problem with `getComponent()` at all, it's a problem with the datasource definitions. Regardless of what you code in the `documentId` property, you're just telling it to save both datasources onto whatever document corresponds to the UNID in the URL.

Comment: This is the declaration on my datasource.
`<xp:this.data >
  <xp:dominoDocument var="dts_proposta" formName="fm_atp" computeWithForm="onload" concurrencyMode="force" >
  </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>`

If i put `ignoreRequestParams="true"` in the `data` tag the error continues, if I put in the `dominoDocument` tag the page don't even load the data.

Comment: In the question you mentioned that the user is editing two documents. What about the other dominoDocument datasource? getComponent() just gets the nearest component with that ID, but it's not clear from the question where you're using that or for what code. I'm not convinced getComponent is the cause of your problems with a rich text field bound to document B being saved in document A.

Comment: The Xpage loads with the data source `dts_proposta` in both documents. The get component is in a method in a Script Library and is called in a button on the Xpage. This function is used to save the data, so it have to get the data from the fields and save in it's own documents. The both tabs use the datasource with the same name, since the same Xpage is used to open the documents, thats why I think the error is the getComponent method.

Comment: If they use the same datasource, then as far as I'm aware both tabs will be saving the same document, not different documents. Also my understanding is `getComponent` can't work in a Script Library - it doesn't have the relevant context. In the training I run I always recommend passing any relevant components as a parameter into the Script Library function. It's what XPages OpenLog Logger also requires.

Comment: I added a edit to the question explaining better my situation, please take a look if possible.

Comment: Manipulating rich text content via scoped variables is not an approach I would recommend. Obviously the source code for the dominoDocument datasource is not available, but I suspect it's far from straightforward. I'd recommend additional datasources with `ignoreRequestParams` set to true.

BUT, if you're already storing the values in scoped variables, why are you going to the component? By the time your code runs, the value from the component will have been passed to the scoped variable. The only times it wouldn't is in a validator (already on component) or `immediate=true` on event